# Flutter widget test, find child widget within a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a stateful widget `MainProgression` I would like to test:

```
class MainProgression extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainProgression({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MainProgressionState createState() => MainProgressionState();
}

class MainProgressionState extends State<MainProgression> {
  int _currentStep = 0;

  void continued() {}

  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Scrollbar(
        isAlwaysShown: true,
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: ListView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          children: <Widget>[
            Stepper(
              type: StepperType.vertical,
              currentStep: _currentStep,
              steps: <Step>[
                Step(
                  title: const Text('Initialize a New Flutter Release'),
                  content: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ConductorSubsteps(continued: continued),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This widget has a child widget `Step` with a content of another widget `ConductorSubsteps`:

```
class ConductorSubsteps extends StatefulWidget {
  const ConductorSubsteps({
    Key? key,
    required this.continued,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final VoidCallback continued;

  @override
  ConductorSubstepsState createState() => ConductorSubstepsState();
}

class ConductorSubstepsState extends State<ConductorSubsteps> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        const CheckboxListTile(
          value: false,
          onChanged: null,
          title: Text('Substep 1'),
        ),
        const CheckboxListTile(
          value: false,
          onChanged: null,
          title: Text('Substep 2'),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            widget.continued();
          },
          child: const Text('Continue'),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Now I would like to test if `ConductorSubsteps` is interacting with its parent widget `MainProgression` correctly, since `ConductorSubsteps` is modifying some of the state of the parent widget through the `continued` method being passed.

So now I set up a widget test file:

```
      await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
        home: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            MainProgression(
              releaseState: state,
              stateFilePath: defaultStateFilePath(const LocalPlatform()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));

      expect(find.byType(Stepper), findsOneWidget);
      expect(find.text('Substep 1'), findsOneWidget);
```

Since `Stepper` is a widget inside `MainProgression` and `ConductorSubstepsState` (which is inside `MainProgression`) has a `CheckboxListTile` widget with a title of `'Substep 1'`. By pumping the parent widget, I would expect that both `expect` would fulfill.

But none of them does. How do I locate the child widgets in this case and test their interaction with the parent widgets?